# Can we predict the data from the Hash value?

Tags: hash, blockchain

I saw that Deterministic is one of the property of Hashing. So can we predict the data on which we performed hasing algo by checking the hash output value?

Eg. If me and my friend uses the same hashign algo on our individual data. And at some point we both got ABCD as hash output value. So in that We can get to know on each other on which data we are performing hashing, right?

Comment: Main property of hash functions is that you cannot go back to the original input knowing the output. If you know that two identical hashes where generated you cannot say if the input was the same or it is an hash collision (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_collision)

Comment: *So in that We can get to know on each other on which data we are performing hashing, right?* No. Wrong.